# Service in android crashes after several hours

Tags: android, android-service

i tried to write a simple service for an android device. it looks like

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // do something

    // new alarm
    setNextAlarm(context);

}
public static void setNextAlarm(Context context) {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MainReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, myIntent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    // trigger
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    // here is possible that trigger time will be different by each call
    long triggerTime =  computeNextTriggerTime();
    long triggerAtTime = cal.getTimeInMillis() + triggerTime;

    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, triggerAtTime, triggerTime, pendingIntent);
}
```

Well, I noticed that it works, but sometimes it crashes after days or hours of using and I'm quite sure, that it is not because of the code, that do the logic and that I didn't post here.

The trigger time is between 10 and 30 minutes.

Every help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Can you add some Error Log for it?

Comment: but we should be notified what kind of errors you getting, we can not get what the problem by guessing...please put some logcat here